# Datos de BD en numero convertir a texto ANGULAR

Tags: angular

Tengo unos datos que me traigo de la Base de Datos que son los siguientes:

```
Estado
0
-1
1
2
```

El cual necesito convertir el campo `ESTADO`

```
0: Creado
-1 : Cancelado
1 : Aprobado
2: Finalizado
```

Este es mi código:

```html
<div class="card obtenido"  *ngFor="let viaje of viaje.viaje">
    <div class="card-body">
        <h5 class="card-title">{{viaje.id}}</h5>
        <li>{{viaje.fecha}} </li>
        <li>{{viaje.ciudadNombre}} </li>
        <li [ngSwitch]="Estado">{{viaje.estado}} </li>
        <a href="#" class="btn btn-outline-danger">Cancelar</a>
    </div>             
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Segun Angular no deberias usar metodos en la plantilla. Una forma elegante de hacerlo es utilizando un pipe.

Creas un nuevo componente format-status.pipe.ts con el contenido:

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';

@Pipe({
    name: 'formatStatus'
})
export class FormatStatusPipe implements PipeTransform {
    transform(value: String): String {
        if(value==='0'){
            return 'creado';
        } else if(...){
        }
    }
}
```

Lo declaras en app.modules.ts

y lo utilizas en tu componente

```
{{viaje.estado | formatStatus}}
```

Comment: excelente respuesta, pero tienes un pequeño detalle , el `value `es de tipo   `string` y despues haces  `value===0`, es decir nunca sera cero

Comment: @JackNavaRow Tienes razón, gracias, respuesta editada

Answer (score 1):

Puedes crear una función para que tome el valor **viaje.estado** y retorne el texto que necesitas así por ejemplo:

```
checkValue(data){
    switch(data){
      case 0:
        return "Opcion 1";
        break;
      case 1:
        return "Opcion 2"
        break;
      //etc...
    }
}
```

y en la vista cambiar tu li a

```html
<li>{{ checkValue(viaje.estado) }} </li>
```

Comment: Gracias PRO MAQUINA ME sirvio demasiado

Comment: Bro otra pregunta Tengo un campo tipo date como hago para que me traiga solo la fecha que coloco el me esta trayendo asi la fecha 2019-01-11T00:00:00

Comment: usa datepipe de angualar aca la documentación https://angular.io/api/common/DatePipe

Comment: para tu caso seria algo así **{ viaje.fecha | 'shortDate' }**

Comment: Es una respuesta valida pero no te acostumbres a usar métodos en la plantilla, en vez de estos utiliza pipes: https://blog.appverse.io/why-it-is-a-bad-idea-to-use-methods-in-the-html-templates-with-angular-2-30d49f0d3b16

Comment: { viaje.fecha | 'shortDate' }  ME salio error

Comment: **{{ dateObj | date:'shortDate' }}** debe ir así segun la documentación

Comment: Ya me sirvio bro

Answer (score 1):

lo ideal es que definas unas constantes para esos valores y luego al Traer el resultado te retorne el string , dejo un ejemplo:

```js
const estados = ["Creado", "Aprobado", "Finalizado" ,"Cancelado"]

function obtenerEstado (i){
return i >=0 ? estados[i] : estados[3]


}
console.log("Creado?", obtenerEstado(0))
console.log("Aprobado?", obtenerEstado(1))

console.log("FInalizado?", obtenerEstado(2))
console.log("Cancelado?", obtenerEstado(-1))
```

Esta respuesta no usa un for , por lo tanto la eficiencia es la ideal [O(n)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_complexity#Table_of_common_time_complexities)